Unwanted text replacement of two hyphens with an em-dash
My settings in Keyboard→Text replacements had two entries, 'pq' and 'omw'.  Since I never use them and don't recall creating them, I assume they are Apple's "helpful" defaults.
But every time I type two hyphens consecutively, "something" changes it to an em-dash.
This is unnecessary because I always type¹ an actual em-dash where appropriate.  And it's unwanted because --  is (or used to be) valuable to place before an e-mail signature.
I have a similar problem with " sometimes being auto-replaced by “ which causes havoc when editing shell scripts.
How can I make it stop?
(Interestingly, the em-dash did not happen in the above paragraph!  But it happened every time I created an e-mail sig.)
¹with Unicode Hex Input, which I've made my default keyboard.

Are text replacements built into Unicode Hex Input?  I know that's possible because of the way that input method works.  I successfully made changes to it before they changed it from XML to binary.

Which application do you use for mail?

Apple's mail.app — but unwanted replacements happen in other apps, though apparently not in Safari.  I guess I need to check specific app settings.

Somewhat counterintuitively, the setting to replace two dashes with an em dash is not located in Text Replacements, but in Text Input:

Open System Preferences
Select Keyboard.
Under Text Input, press the Edit button next to the relevant input source:

Disable "Use smart quotes and dashes":


This will turn off the em dash replacement.
Note that this setting will also turn off smart quotes system-wide. Luckily, you can configure specific apps to use smart quotes by using the app's Edit > Substitutions menu.
For example, in the Mail app, compose a new message (otherwise the Edit > Substitutions menu is grayed out), select Edit > Substitutions > Show Substitutions:

and turn on or off the options you need:

